# Nodejs - Download Image, save to Local Disk Storage and Push to S3

Tags: node.js, image, amazon-s3, fs, multer

I am facing facing problem to convert the raw binary data recieved from API into Image and Push to AWS S3

Problem to Solve - Convert raw data into valid image and save to disk.

[Click here - Response from API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46hDX.png)

```
        var base64EncodedStr = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(binary_image_data)))
        let image = `data:image/jpeg;base64 , ${base64EncodedStr}`;
        let data = image.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, "");
        let buff = Buffer.from(data, 'base64');
        await fs.writeFileSync('image.jpeg', buff)
```

Comment: Mind to share some of your code?

Comment: Please share the code. Does the image come to you in base64? a blob?

Comment: @Fabio Please check the response of API, I have attached above, code shared, Thanks

Comment: Acutally I suppose you `binary_image_data` is -- as the name suggests -- already a binary buffer. But that's hard to say without context. Why not just save that to the disk without any manipulation ...

Comment: @derpirscher need to push to AWS S3, if I directly Push to S3, Image is not getitng manipulated upon download,

Comment: With your code the image is not saved then? in case it is not saved, are you sure it is in base 64? because if it is, then the code should be correct and the image should save itself without any problems locally.